# Dualboot Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

So I have an old computer with WIndows 11. Windows 11 is still slow on a decade old Acer. I want to install Ubuntu but want to keep Windows. When I do a dualboot, I always have to force boot to the GRUB menu. How do I always make the GRUB menu show up when I turn on the computer?

Comment: Is grub earlier in the boot order than Windows?